# Python function returns value while debug, but None while run

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a function that works correctly when run from a debugger, but returns `None` otherwise.

```
class HotelRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, guestlst=[]):
        self.guestlst = guestlst
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.guestlst == []:
            self.guestlst.append("empty")
        return 'HotelRoom(guestlst=%r)' % self.guestlst
    def maybeFill(self, newGuests):
        # return new guestlist on success; return None on failure
        if self.guestlst == ["empty"]:
            self.guestlst = newGuests
            return self.guestlst
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = HotelRoom()
    print(h.maybeFill(["Nathan"]))
```

If I step through with a debugger, this works fine, and it has the expected output of `["Nathan"]`.

If I just run it, the output is `None`.

Why does the function's output depend on whether it is being run in a debugger?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can copy from your question and run in our interpreters/ide's.  You need to do the work for us.  If your function is returning None then  `check_guest ` is False. As an aside the conditional statement should be `if check_guest :` Or `self.hotel_rooms` is empty or `(checked_room.better_than(check_guest) and ...` is evaluating False.

Comment: Chained boolean operations ,`checked_room.better_than(check_guest) and checked_room.guestslst == ["empty"]`, seem to frequently be *gotchas* - put parens around how you want the operations grouped/executed.

Comment: @wwii - added a demo

Comment: @CharlesDuffy have you opened the pastebin by chance? half of it is just class definition which is required, I already omitted most of the code so when it is run - but thank you for your helpful advice

Comment: It's only required if you can't create the same problem with a simpler class.

Comment: I've edited this to have a proper [mre], and will answer it should it be reopened (unless someone else gets there first).

Comment: (BTW, I wrote the `__repr__()` function the way I did because that's how `__repr__()` functions are *supposed* to be written -- human-readable printouts should be in a `__str__` function, not a `__repr__` function; a `__repr__` should emit code that recreates the object when run, if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `__repr__` function changes the value it's supposed to be printing. When you're in the debugger, the act of the debugger trying to display the representation of the value to you *changes that value*, by changing `[]` to `['empty']`.

Because the `maybeFill` function compares the list to `['empty']`, it returns false when the actual value is `[]`, which it always will be if `repr()` was never called.

A less-surprising `__repr__` will only *display* the value, but never *change* it. Consider, then, leaving the empty value as `[]` instead of ever transforming it to `['empty']`:

```
class HotelRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, guestlst=[]):
        self.guestlst = guestlst
    def __str__(self):
        if self.guestlst:
            return 'Hotel room, with guests: %s' % ', '.join(self.guestlst)
        return 'Empty hotel room'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'HotelRoom(guestlst=%r)' % self.guestlst
    def maybeFill(self, newGuests):
        # return new guestlist on success; return None on failure
        if self.guestlst == []:
            self.guestlst = newGuests
            return self.guestlst
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = HotelRoom()
    if h.maybeFill(["Nathan", "John"]) == None:
        print("If you see this, the problem is not solved")
    print(h)
```

As you can see in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/drlN6w, the above works even when no debugger is causing `__repr__` or `__str__` to be called early.

Comment: Although your edit of my post was so far from the original that it was hard to corelate, your tip about ['empty'] vs [] was the solution. About the the __str__ - sadly it a part of an assignment given in python beginners class and we were told explicitly to use __repr__....

Comment: The original was too long and meandering to be a [mre]; building the **shortest possible code** that generates the same problem is part of what you're expected to do when asking a question. Next time, if you do that yourself, you won't need someone else to do it for you.